# How does one achieve this layout?

Tags: chapters, alignment

[image]

I want to  recreate the layout when starting a new chapter as illustrated in the appended picture - how can I achieve this black bar?

Comment: The question is not very well-defined. Here are some questions for you: (a) The attached picture shows starting a new section, not a new chapter. (b) Is the black bar meant to be just above the section start, or is it meant to be at the bottom of the header? (c) Is the black bar referring to the entire line (both the thick and thin parts), or are you referring to only the thick part?

Comment: @WillieWong (b) just above the section start, (c) both

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\hrule
\noindent\rule[8pt]{5cm}{8pt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can counter the effect of nonzero `\parskip` as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\parskip=1ex
\begin{document}


\hrule
\noindent\rule[8pt]{5cm}{8pt}

\bigskip

\hrule
\vspace{-1ex}
\noindent\rule[8pt]{5cm}{8pt}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I try this there is a considerable margin between the black bar and the black line, what could the reason be?

Comment: It's hard to tell. A compilable example would be nice for people here to help.

Comment: You can reduce the size of the `\rule` up to a point (`\baselineskip`), or use `\hrule height2pt width2.5cm` (for example)

Comment: @modnar I think it's because I have set my `\parskip` to `1ex`. Any way this works with my setting?

Comment: @Descrates, how about the above modified answer?

Comment: @modnar didn't know about  this command, thanks!

Comment: @Descrates, you are welcome!